# How could I get notifications in my app when a different app starts on Mac OS X?

Tags: cocoa, macos, notifications

Can I register a listener, so that before an application starts or just after it's started, I can get a notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Especially, the notifications, such as `NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification` / `NSWorkspaceDidLaunchApplicationNotification`